# How to replace the double backslash with a single backslash

Tags: c#

I want to replace the double backslash with a single backslash.

Using

```
string destinationFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(msiDirectory, fileName).Replace('\\', '\'');
```

gives

> C:\Hg\temp'LogFile.txt

How can I have

> C:\Hg\temp\LogFile.txt

After using some of the answers (`Replace('\\\\', '\\')` or `Replace(@'\\', @'\')`) here I get C:\Hg\temp\\LogFile.txt

Comment: \\\\ is a double backslash.

Comment: `Replace('\\\\', '\\')` or `Replace(@'\\', @'\')`

Comment: Are you sure you're not seeing the escaping of the debugger?

Comment: Click the magnifying glass next to the string in the debugger to see the unescaped string.

Comment: using Replace('\\\\', '\\') or Replace(@'\\', @'\') is  giving C:\Hg\temp\\LogFile.txt

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try using

```
string destinationFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(msiDirectory, fileName)
                                       .Replace(@"\\", @"\");
```

`@` has to be there before the string.

Example:

```
string path = "C:\\Hg\\temp\\LogFile.txt";
string output = path.Replace(@"\\", @"\"); 

output >>>
C:\Hg\temp\LogFile.txt
```

Strings use backlashes as escape characters. By putting `@` in front of the string, you tell the compiler that you won't use a backslash as the escape character but plain backslash.

You can also do that by escaping the backslashes like below.

```
string destinationFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(msiDirectory, fileName)
                                       .Replace("\\\\", "\\");
```

Notice that two backslashes here mean only one plain backslash in writing. And you can try it out by printing the strings to the console.

Read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim)

Comment: Replace('\\\\', '\\') or Replace(@'\\', @'\') is giving C:\Hg\temp\\LogFile.txt

Comment: msiDirectory is C:\temp\

Comment: it gives C:\temp\\LogFile.txt

Comment: Initially string destinationFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(msiDirectory, fileName) gives C:\temp\\LogFile.txt

Comment: So I want to transform C:\temp\\LogFile.txt to C:\temp\LogFile.txt

Comment: It is still giving the double backslash

Comment: Even string destinationFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(msiDirectory, fileName).Replace(@"\\", @"\")).Replace(@"\\", @"\"); gives C:\temp\\LogFile.txt

Comment: I have tried string destinationFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(msiDirectory, fileName).Replace(@"\\", @"$");, this gives C:\temp\\LogFile.txt.  What`s wrong with this?  It still does not give C:\temp$LogFile.txt

Comment: string output = path.Replace(@"\\", @"\");  is still giving C:\Hg\temp\\LogFile.txt

Comment: @user4657208 exact your issue im facing,

Answer (score 2):

@jackjop already mentioned but you can also try below code which also works:

```
var destinationFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(msiDirectory, fileName).Replace("\\\\", "\\");
```

Answer (score 0):

FWIW `Replace("\\", "\")` works fine in VB

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
string destinationFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(msiDirectory, fileName).Replace(@"\\", @"\");
```