# How can i replace both Forward(//) and backword(\) slash in a string to forward slash(/)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

i have a string like this:
***D:\\folder\\folder\\folder/folder/folder***
since it is mixed up with forward and backword slashes the directory couldnt 
find file but if i change it like this 
***D:\folder\folder\folder\folder\folder***
the path is correct .

i have try to do it like this

```
sourceStreamId=D:\\folder\\folder\\folder/folder/folder
string appdomain = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath;
string destinationFile=System.IO.Path.Combine(appdomain,sourceStreamId).Replace("\\", @"\");
```

but this resulted in a string like this 
***D:\\folder\\folder\\folder/folder/folder***

can anybody sugest a work around for this

i have been here:[How to replace the double backslash with a single backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32266746/how-to-replace-the-double-backslash-with-a-single-backslash) but that string only have double backword slash i have both forward and backword

Comment: `"\\"` and `@"\"` are the same thing.

Comment: but when i use ```\\``` for the path the file is not found? using ```\``` is correct!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace the double backslash with a single backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32266746/how-to-replace-the-double-backslash-with-a-single-backslash)

Comment: You are replacing the same thing. `"\\"` is `"\"` and `@"\"` is `"\"`.

Comment: To solve that you need to add `@` to `"\\"` like this: `.Replace(@"\\", @"\");`

Comment: but what if i have to replace both forward```//``` and backword ```\```to only ```\``` this

Comment: no i have tried that to```Replace(@"\\", @"\")``` its a fail

Comment: Check the answer I've posted.

Comment: "its a fail" doesn't describe the result. Please provide a [mcve], and make sure you write the results out to the console - I think it's entirely possible that the string only has single-backslashes already, but you're looking in the debugger which is escaping the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To replace bot just call `Replace` twice:

```
string destinationFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(appdomain,sourceStreamId)
                                       .Replace(@"\\", @"\")
                                       .Replace("/", @"\");
```

References: **[DotNetFiddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AaXUlb)**

Answer (score 1):

try as below:-

```
string destinationFile=System.IO.Path.Combine(appdomain,sourceStreamId).Replace(@"\\", @"\");
```

Eg:-

```
string path = "C:\Hg\temp/test\\LogFile.txt";
path = path.Replace(@"\\", @"\"); 
string output = path.Replace(@"/", @"\");
```

**output >>>
C:\Hg\temp\test\LogFile.txt**

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage Path to fix it for you:

```
var ourceStreamId = "D:\\folder\\folder\\folder/folder/folder";

var path = Path.GetFullPath(ourceStreamId);
Console.WriteLine(path);
//output: D:\folder\folder\folder\folder\folder
```